# nohup SBCL ubuntu couldn't read from standard input

Tags: linux, lisp, sbcl, nohup

On Ubuntu I compiled sbcl 1.0.35 with threading. I can happily use sbcl from the command line and my hunchentoot website works with threading but when I logout it's gone. When I attempt to nohup sbcl

nohup ./src/runtime/sbcl --core output/sbcl.core

I get

(SB-IMPL::SIMPLE-STREAM-PERROR "couldn't read from ~S"  # 9)

I've attempted various combinations of redirecting the standard input to /dev/null or a file and using the script command line option but I don't quite get what is going on.

How do I start sbcl from the command line on linux with nohup and keep my repl(website) running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmity-vk sent me on the right track, thank you. SBCL tries to start a repl when you start it up, and reads from the standard in. When you use `nohup` the standard in is redirected and cannot be read. SBCL then drops to the debugger which tries to read from standard in ... hence the endless loop. The `--script` tag comes close to solving this except that it has a `(quit)` once the script has been read. So I put an endless loop in my script and voila.

so on an ubuntu server with sbcl this should let you start a hunchentoot server

```
sudo nohup ./run-sbcl.sh --script foo.lisp > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
```

where foo.lisp has as its last lines something like

```
(defvar *alive* t)

(loop (sleep 1000) (if (not *alive*) (quit)))
```

Answer (score 3):

RESTAS web-framework ("REST Application Server") by Andrey Moskvitin contains code to properly daemonize SBCL instance. See http://github.com/archimag/restas/blob/master/contrib/restas-daemon.lisp. You can easily rip off RESTAS-specific parts.

Answer (score 3):

You could start SBCL in [Gnu Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and then detach from the session.

This also gives you the possibility to reattach to your REPL later.